# Java Regex group 0

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please help me to explain the following code? Thanks. I am a little bit confused about the regex grouping.

```
public static String evaluate(String s) {
    if (s == null) return "";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*").matcher(s);

    if (m.find()) {
        MatchResult mr = m.toMatchResult();
        return mr.group(0);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) may interest you. `group(0)` is entire match, `group(1)` is match inside first set of `(...)` in your regex, and so on.

Answer (score 25):

Hope this makes the *group 0* more clear:

**Example:**

```
    String str = "start123456end"; // Your input String


    //                                 Group#1 Group#2
    //                                   |      |  
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("start([0-9]*)(end)");
    //                           |<--- Group#0 --->|


    Matcher m = p.matcher(str); // Create a matcher for regex and input

    while( m.find() ) // As long as your regex matches something
    {
        System.out.println("group#0:\t" + m.group()); // Or: m.group(0)
        System.out.println("group#1:\t" + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("group#2:\t" + m.group(2));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
group#0:    start123456end
group#1:    123456
group#2:    end
```

You can *"store"* some parts of your regex into groups. in my example you have 3 of them (groups are between `(`and `)`):

- **Group 1:** numbers between *start* and *end* words.
- **Group 2:** the *end* word only
- **Group 0:** thats the *whole* thing that matches your pattern - group 0 is reserved and will always return the whole match, while all others are optional and defined by you.

---

**According to your code:**

**Example:**

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*").matcher("123456end"); // Matches all numbers

if( m.find() )
{
    System.out.println(m.group(0)); // m.group() possible too
}
```

There only one group: `0`!

**Output:** `123456` (= group 0)

now lets put some more groups into the pattern:

**Code:**

```
    //                            Group#1      Group#2
    //                              |            |
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9])[0-9]([0-9])*").matcher(str); // Matches all numbers
    //                           |<---- Group#0 ---->|

    if( m.find() )
    {
        System.out.println("group#0:\t" + m.group(0)); // m.group() possible too
        System.out.println("group#1:\t" + m.group(1)); // 1st digit
        System.out.println("group#2:\t" + m.group(2)); // 3rd digit
    }
```

There are two more groups now.

**Output:**

```
group#0:    123456
group#1:    1
group#2:    6
```

---

I recommend you this documentation: [**Lesson: Regular Expressions**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html). Realy start from first chapter and try examples by your own.

**Additional:**

- [Java Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (see [3.4. Grouping and Backreference](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#regex_grouping) for grouping)
- [Guide to Regular Expressions in Java (Part 1)](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/)
- [Guide to Regular Expressions in Java (Part 2)](http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-2/)

Answer (score 13):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

> **Group zero denotes the entire pattern**, so the expression `m.group(0)` is equivalent to `m.group()`.

In other words, `mr.group(0)` is the entire match.

Comment: can u please explain it in a more understandable way? sorry, i am new to java regex ...