# How to split a string in two using a pivot a number?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a string into two parts using regex, but apparently, the regex is greedy so in the first group it adds a little bit more.

Example of string: "This is a phrase 22ext"

Desired result:

- Group 0 = "This is a phrase"
- Group 1 = "22"
- The "ex"t iss discarded.

I'm using the following Regex (in java):

```
[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*
```

It works for Group 1, but in Group 0, it includes "22ext" as well.

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't give the desired output because you didn't add the first part of it in a group, so **you only have one group in your regex** <sup>1</sup>. You can fix that by using:

```
([^0-9]*)([0-9]+).*
```

And then you can find your two strings in "Group 1" and "Group 2". Note that ["Group 0" is the *full match*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14385873/4934172).

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJtEwj/1).

A better and shorter way is to use the following regex:

```
(\D*)(\d+)
```

Which matches any non-numeric characters in the first group *(until it reaches the first numeric characters)* and then it matches the upcoming numeric characters *including all Unicode digits* in the second group.

And you can decide whether or not to include the `.*` at the end.

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/zw4Ati/1).

---

### References:

- [Difference between `[0-9]` and `\d`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/4934172).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>"Group 0" is the *full match* for the entire pattern, so you need to use "Group 1" and "Group 2".</sub>

Comment: Your "solution" regex is equivalent to the author's. Only the group numbering is changed. It would be just as easy to pick the other group, arguably easier.

Comment: @Obicere, That's not true! The OP's regex only has **one group**, so I 1) pointed that out. 2) Provided an alternative solution to the problem described in the question _which I believe is better_.

Comment: There is literally no difference between the grouping count. This is the equivalent of padding an array with `null` entries. Properly referencing the group is a better solution.

Comment: @Obicere `There is literally no difference between the grouping count` The OP specifically said that he wants the output split in _two_ groups. I explained why his regex doesn't do that **and** provided an additional solution to the problem. What do you see wrong with that?! I'm not sure what you mean by _"Properly referencing the group is a better solution"_.