# Issue with regex in Golang

Tags: regex, go, regex-group

I am trying to create a regex to parse specific string .

The current string is `abcd_1.263.0.15-8zz00df.yml` and I want to parse only `1.263.0.15-8zz00df` out of it.

Tried already with this expression `"_\K.*(?=\.)"` but its not working in Golan and giving me pattern error. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/TrB1yVM3q15 or https://go.dev/play/p/zXlwWBq0rlM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Go* uses *RE2* regex engine, that does not support *lookaheads*, *lookbehinds* and other PCRE goodies like *\K*

See this [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) of the different regex engines.

You could however use this regex:

```
[^_-]+-[^.]+
```

See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qKGozu/1).

Explained:

```
[^_-]+   # a character that is not "_" or "-", one or more times
-        # a literal "-"
[^.]+    # a character that is not a dot, one or more times
```

Answer (score 1):

Just reposting one of @mkopriva's snippets with a sentence,

not everything needs to be done with regular expressions :

```
    s := "abcd_1.263.0.15-8zz00df.yml"

    if i := strings.IndexByte(s, '_'); i > -1 {
        s = s[i+1:]
    }
    if i := strings.LastIndexByte(s, '.'); i > -1 {
        s = s[:i]
    }

    fmt.Println(s)
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TrB1yVM3q15)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** You can simply use the regular expression:

```
_(.*)\.
```

The `*` matches greedily, which means that it will match everything until the last '.'  - this is exactly what you need. Your match is in group 1.

---

Why are you using the `\K` matcher? Your regular expression works like this:

```
_(.*)(?=\.)
```

and group 1 contains your match.

Note: a very helpful tool to test regular expressions is this site: https://regexr.com/

Comment: I tried this but getting error when using ?

https://regex101.com/r/I9r2kw/1

Comment: @johnwatson I simplified the regex and it should work now.

Comment: thanks @Stefan..but new pattern is including underscore and dot from starting n ending which is not expected

Comment: You should use group 1 because the match you need is in group 1. You can see it on the right side on your regex101 link. Learn more about groups here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484091/9698467

Comment: thanks @Stefan.. can u also please tell how I can use this group 1...

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more precise match for that string format, you can use a capture group, and as there do not seem to be spaces in the string you can use `\S` instead of `.`

```
_(\S+)\.yml$
```

- `_` Match the leading underscore
- `(\S+)` Capture 1+ non whitespace chars in group 1
- `\.yml` Match `.yml`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVAddE/1).

For example

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main(){
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`_(\S+)\.yml$`)
    res := re.FindStringSubmatch("abcd_1.263.0.15-8zz00df.yml")
    fmt.Printf("%v", res[1])
}
```

Output

```
1.263.0.15-8zz00df
```

---

Or a broader match, capturing till before the last occurrence of the dot:

```
_(\S+)\.
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZrrXmJ/1).